# Bash: How to compose functions where the inner function will return an argument

Tags: git, bash

Currently I am doing

```
git log --author="AlanH" --invert-grep -n1 --format=%H
```

to get the commit hash of the last commit that was not by me. Then I use that to do `git rebase -i <commit_hash>`, where the `commit_hash` has to be manually copied and pasted from the previous command's output.

In bash I would like to do something like this

```
squash() {
  git rebase -i (git log --author="AlanH" --invert-grep -n1 --format=%H)
}
```

so that the inner command completes first, then feeds that to the `rebase` command. 
How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell-specific part of the answer is what everyone else said: `$(cmd)` runs `cmd` and splices in its output.

This will make no difference in terms of end result, but for scripting purposes, one should usually use `git rev-list` rather than `git log` (because `git rev-list` is specifically designed to be used from scripts, while `git log` is mostly meant for use by humans).  The main difference with using `rev-list` is that you can drop the format directive—being aimed at scripts, `rev-list` already prints hashes—and must add the starting point `HEAD` that `git log` supplies by default:

```
git rebase -i $(git rev-list --author="AlanH" --invert-grep -n1 HEAD)
```

(There's no really strong reason to prefer `git rev-list` here, although the resulting command is a few characters shorter.)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `rev-list` (which is appropriate here).

Comment: You can also pipe: `git rev-list --author="AlanH" --invert-grep -n1 HEAD | xargs git rebase -i`

Comment: @hIpPy: yes, although `xargs` has a different intended use, which is not really appropriate for `git rebase`. (Looks like you typo'd `-n2` and fixed it to `-n1`)

Comment: @torek, yes that was a typo. What's wrong with `xargs` and `rebase`?

Comment: @hIpPy: it's not exactly *wrong*, it's more misleading (my opinion). It's a bit like using ∑v to get the single value out of a vector, which implies that the sum of all the vector elements is also a valid solution, when in fact the problem requires that the vector have just one element. `xargs` is "for" (as much as any command has an intended purpose) running some other command *repeatedly*, as often as needed, but we intend to run `git rebase` only once here.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
git rebase -i (git log --author="AlanH" --invert-grep -n1 --format=%H)
```

by

```
git rebase -i $(git log --author="AlanH" --invert-grep -n1 --format=%H)
```

---

See: [3.5.4 Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)

Answer (score 1):

Put a `$` before the braces:

```
git rebase -i $(git log --author="AlanH" --invert-grep -n1 --format=%H)
```

This will evaluate everything inside it (which will be the commit id) and then pass it to the `rebase` command.